# Accessing Composite Datawindow Objects

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

The PowerBuilder (version 9) help explains that you can use both the dot notation and the Describe and Modify methods to access objects nested in a composite datawindow. I'm having trouble doing this in an object because the objects aren't being found at runtime.

The user object I'm working with is a level or two down the inheritance chain, and it has a composite datawindow on it that contains four report datawindows (dw_1 through dw_4). When I try to see what the composite datawindow has by looking at the Describe results of datawindow.objects, I don't get a list of

> dw_1  dw_2  dw_3  dw_4

What it gives me instead is this:

> obj_4112034 obj_4112035 obj_4112036 obj_4112037

The object names can change each time I run it. I'm guessing there is some dynamic processing that is causing this, but I'm not sure. Why isn't PowerBuilder returning the object names as defined in development mode? Is there a way I can work around this so I can access the properties of the nested report datawindows?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "dw_composite.objects", but you can usually get all objects in a tabseperated string using

```
string s_objects
s_objects=yourdatawindow.describe("Datawindow.objects")
```

Answer (score 0):

`dw_data.modify('datawindow.crosstab.staticmode=yes');`

From PB Help:

> A string indicating whether a dynamic crosstab should be put into a static mode. The dynamic crosstab remains in static mode until you set StaticMode to No. While the dynamic crosstab is in static mode, you can manipulate the properties of individual columns.

Comment: Thank you but I am using a composite datawindow, not a crosstab.